# How to pass values from one component to another in react-native android

Tags: reactjs, react-native, create-react-native-app

I'm new in react-native android, I wanna know How to pass values from one component to another in react-native android, I just wanna to know 2 things,

1. How to pass data
2. How to retrieve data

give any reference or link which is understood easy.thanks advance

Comment: Go through the website https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of passing data,

1. **State** : Used if your component is in the same class you can simply use state to pass data between components
2. **Props** : Used if you want to pass data between different class (child <-> parent).

reference: https://facebook.github.io/react-vr/docs/components-props-and-state.html

React Native also recomend to use state management if your app is getting bigger.

One of the most used state management is by using **REDUX**, 
in short you can make your props behave like a global variable that you can access across your app.

for more detailed introduction you can read this :

https://medium.com/@jonlebensold/getting-started-with-react-native-redux-2b01408c0053

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react-navigation for routing from one component to another,
it's pretty simple to send data in params as you move to a new component. Have a look at the [docs here](https://reactnavigation.org/).

In your `android.js` file, initialize all the routes like below:

```
import Component from './app/components/Component/Component';
import HomeComponent from './app/components/HomeComponent/HomeComponent';
const Mobile = StackNavigator(
{Login: { screen: Component },
Home: { screen: HomeComponent },},
 { initialRouteName: 'Login' },
{ headerMode: 'screen' });
AppRegistry.registerComponent('Mobile', () =>Mobile);
```

Then the login screen will load first, then use this command in a function or constructor to navigate:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Home',{param:'SomeParameter'})
```

In the Home screen constructor print out the `this.props`, and in the console you will find the param key in that object.

Comment: To get the data in 'Home' component, we can use this.props.navigation.getParam('param');